# Don't know where to start to debug this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently doing rail project and I am getting this error whilst testing my spec.

```
 h1) Deleting todo items is successful
 Failure/Error: click_link "Delete"
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [DELETE] "/todo_lists/1/todo_items/1/edit"
 # ./spec/features/todo_items/delete_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/features/todo_items/delete_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your `rake routes` and check what routes you have. Most likely there's no `DELETE` to `/todo_lists/1/todo_items/1/edit` available (and there should be one).

`DELETE` should be issues to `/todo_lists/1/todo_items/1` URL

Edit: in your https://github.com/amidabrian51/odot/blob/master/app/views/todo_items/index.html.erb#L8 it should be `todo_list_todo_item_path(todo_item)`